# How can I execute shared files with apache server on VMware Fusion

Tags: ubuntu, macos, vmware-fusion

I shared my folder with php scripts, located on my mac with **Ubuntu 14.04** deployed on virtual machine **VMware Fusion 6.0.3**.

But when I set apache **DocumentRoot** to this shared folder and run it with browser, I get an error **"Permission denied"**.

Scripts located in **/mnt/hgfs/www/**. I changed permissions to *777* for all files, but still does not work with same error. When I try to change files owner with *sudo*, I get the same error too.

How can I execute shared php script from my mac with apache server, installed on ubuntu on virtual machine?

Please, help